# BIML, attribute SortKeyPosition is not set as an attribute in the OutputColum section of component Merge Join

Tags: ssis, biml

On a Merge Join component generated by biml, I get the error below.
When double clicking on the merge join component in SSIS, I found in the SSIS xml code that it added the SortKeyPosition="1" in the OutputColumn section. I was able to execute the package successfuly afterwise.
How can I set the SortKeyPosition in biml for this specific section OutputColumn.
Below, the error and my biml code.

---

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Warning: The IsSorted property of MERGEJOIN_wcs_customer_order_line.Outputs[Output] is set to TRUE, but all of its output columns' SortKeyPositions are set to zero.
>   [MERGEJOIN_wcs_customer_order_line [130]] Error: The column with the SortKeyPosition value of 0 is not valid. It should be 1.
>   [MERGEJOIN_wcs_customer_order_line [130]] Error: The column with the SortKeyPosition value of 0 is not valid. It should be 2.
>   [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "MERGEJOIN_wcs_customer_order_line" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".

---

```
<MergeJoin Name="MERGEJOIN_<#=table.Name#>" JoinType="LeftOuterJoin">
    <LeftInputPath OutputPathName="SORT_<#=table.Name#>.Output">
        <Columns>
            <#
            indexSortKey=1;
                foreach(var column in table.Columns) {
                if (column.GetTag("ColumnRole")=="BK")
                {
                #>
                    <Column SourceColumn="DC_<#=column.Name#>" SortKeyPosition="<#=indexSortKey.ToString()#>" TargetColumn="STG_<#=column.Name#>" />              
                <#
                    indexSortKey++;
                }
                else
                {#>
                    <Column SourceColumn="DC_<#=column.Name#>" TargetColumn="STG_<#=column.Name#>"/>
                <#}
            } #>
        </Columns>
    </LeftInputPath>
    <RightInputPath OutputPathName="OLEDBD_ODS_<#=table.Name#>.Output">
        <Columns>                                           
            <#
            indexSortKey=1;
                foreach(var column in table.Columns) {
                if (column.GetTag("ColumnRole")=="BK")
                {#>

                <Column SourceColumn="<#=column.Name#>" SortKeyPosition="<#=indexSortKey.ToString()#>" TargetColumn="ODS_<#=column.Name#>" />             
                <#
                    indexSortKey++;
                }
                else
                {#>
                    <Column SourceColumn="<#=column.Name#>" TargetColumn="ODS_<#=column.Name#>"/>
                <#}
            } #>
        </Columns>
    </RightInputPath>
    <JoinKeys>
        <#foreach(var column in table.Columns.Where(i=> i.GetTag("ColumnRole")=="BK" )) { #>
            <JoinKey LeftColumn="<#=column.Name#>" RightColumn="<#=column.Name#>"></JoinKey>
        <# } #>
    </JoinKeys>
</MergeJoin>
```

Comment: Are your datasource outputs properly marked as `IsSorted` and with the correct `SortKeyPosition`s?

Comment: Yes they are set properly in SSIS GUI and in the SSIS code as cachedSortKeyPosition :

                  <inputColumns>
                    <inputColumn cachedDataType="i8" cachedName="DC_order_id" cachedSortKeyPosition="1" lineageId="Package\DIMs to ODS wcs_customer_order_line\SORT_wcs_customer_order_line.Outputs[Output].Columns[DC_order_id]" refId="Package\DIMs to ODS wcs_customer_order_line\MERGEJOIN_wcs_customer_order_line.Inputs[SORT_wcs_customer_order_line_Output_MERGEJOIN_wcs_customer_order_line].Columns[DC_order_id]">

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you managed to get to the bottom of this but I was having the exact same issue and have worked out what the problem is.

You need to ensure that when you specify the JoinKeys, the LeftColumn and RightColumn values should match what you aliased the columns as in the input paths sections above. In your case the JoinKeys section should be defined as follows:

```
<JoinKeys>
    <#foreach(var column in table.Columns.Where(i=> i.GetTag("ColumnRole")=="BK" )) { #>
        <JoinKey LeftColumn="STG_<#=column.Name#>" RightColumn="ODS_<#=column.Name#>"></JoinKey>
    <# } #>
</JoinKeys>
```

Hope this helps!

Fiaz

Comment: Many thanks, I already figured it out but your answer is perfect!
Thanks again.